# Restheart add an new document in an shard collection

Tags: restheart

I want to add an new document in an mongodb existant collection. But this collection is a shard collection. My shard key is _id.

POST http://ip:8080/db/coll

```
{"CODE_LOG":260,"Date": {"$date" : "2015-10-27T18:21:37.55Z" }}
```

I get this error :

```
{"http status code":400,"http status description":"Bad Request","message":"Write request for sharded collection must specify the shardkey. Use the 'shardkey' query parameter."}
```

I don't want to specify the value of the shardkey.

Answer (score 1):

The error (code 61) is from MongoDB. RESTHeart just manages it and returns the error message that you reported with response status code 400 BAD REQUEST.

See error codes [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/base/error_codes.err)

> error_code("ShardKeyNotFound", 61)

However the restheart documentation page about [shardkey](https://restheart.org/learn/shard-keys/) reports

> When a shared collection has shard key different than _id or a compound shard key, the shardkey query parameter must be used.

You should check your configuration and make sure that the shard key is actually only the _id.